# Incorrect x axis plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

`enter code here`[enter image description here][1]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
setwd('C:/Users/nchatterjee2/Desktop')
df <- read.csv("PD.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",",row.names=NULL, fill = T)
head(df)

#plotting
df<-ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=Day,y=Biomass,color = factor(Year))) +

  ylim(0, 10000)+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    plot.background = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

I am trying to plot biomass data for all planting dates from September 15 - October 31. While plotting, it plots dates randomly. I have arranged the data chronologically so I am unable to understand what I did wrong. If I split the data into four ranges (Sept 15- Sept 30, Oct 1-Oct 9 and so on), I do get the right output. 
head(df)
Data frame looks like this: 
head(df)

```
 Day Biomass         Year
1 Sep15    1249 Cool and Dry
2 Sep15    2490 Warm and Dry
3 Sep15    1600 Warm and Dry
4 Sep15    4664 Warm and Dry
5 Sep15    2400 Cool and Wet
6 Sep15     236 Cool and Dry
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7aLE.png
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide more details what you have done so far with code.

Comment: can you please share the output of `str(head(YOUR_DATA))`. I can't tell what data type it is, but presumably not the `Date` or `POSIXct` types that ggplot can use automatically for an axis. It's likely being interpreted as text and displaying in alphabetical order. You'll need to convert to Date or POSIXct to make it display in order.

Comment: This is my R code. Sorry, I thought I had already put the code in.    library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
setwd('C:/Users/nchatterjee2/Desktop')
df <- read.csv("PD.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",",row.names=NULL, fill = T)
head(df)

#plotting
df<-ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=Day,y=Biomass,color = factor(Year))) +
  
  ylim(0, 10000)+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    plot.background = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )

Comment: @JonSpring.  This is how it looks                                                                                                     
 Day        Biomass         Year
1 Sep15    1249 Cool and Dry
2 Sep15    2490 Warm and Dry
3 Sep15    1600 Warm and Dry
4 Sep15    4664 Warm and Dry
5 Sep15    2400 Cool and Wet
6 Sep15     236 Cool and Dry

Comment: Can you please share the output of `str(head(YOUR_DATA))` (or better yet the output of `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` in the body of your question?

Comment: @user10609402 Hey there - it's nice that you've copy/pasted a print of the top of your data. That's a good start, but it doesn't tell us what class your data is and other important details about the structure. What *does* do that is `dput()` or `str()`, like Jon asked for. **Please type `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:10, ]))` into R, and edit the result into your question**. (Replacing `your_data` with whatever your data is called, `df`, maybe?) This will give us the information we need to really help you.

Comment: In general, for `ggplot`, the order of rows doesn't matter at all. What does matter is the levels of the factor, which will be alphabetical unless you've specified otherwise.

Comment: @Gregor  This is what it shows. Thank you again.                                                                                                           str(head(df))
'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Day    : Factor w/ 48 levels "","Oct1","Oct10",..: 33 33 33 33 33 33
 $ Biomass: num  1249 2490 1600 4664 2400 ...
 $ Year   : Factor w/ 5 levels "","Cool and Dry",..: 2 4 4 4 3 2